# Solving non-linear ordinary differential equation: $(y'')^2-y'y'''=\left(\frac{y'}{x}\right)^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$(y'')^2-y'y'''=\left(\frac{y'}{x}\right)^2$$

I have been struggling to solve this equation by doing following simplifications:
$$y'''y'=(y'')^2-\left(\frac{y'}{x}\right)^2$$
Dividing by $y'$:
$$y'''=\frac{(y'')^2}{y'}-\frac{y'}{x^2}$$
Dividing by $y''$:
$$\frac{y'''}{y''}=\frac{y''}{y'}-\frac{y'}{y''x^2}$$
I can't figure out what goes next since I have never encountered with the last fraction. I would really appreciate any help on the matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most obvious thing to do at the moment is to start by substituting $v=y'$:
$$(v')^2-v\cdot v''=\frac{v^2}{x^2}$$
Let's divide both sides by $v^2$, then integrate both sides with respect to $x$:

$$\int \frac{(v')^2-v\cdot v''}{v^2}=\int \frac{1}{x^2}~dx$$
It is easy to see via the quotient rule that:
$$\left(\frac{v'}{v}\right)'=\frac{v\cdot v''-(v')^2}{v^2}$$
Therefore, we obtain a first-order separable ODE, which is easy to solve:
$$-\frac{v'}{v}=-\frac{1}{x}+C \iff \frac{v'}{v}=\frac{1}{x}+k$$
Where $k:=-C$. All that remains to do is to solve for $v(x)$ explicitly, substitute back for $v=y'$ and integrate both sides with respect to $x$. Doing this will give you an explicit solution for $y(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

*Solving :*

$$ \Bigg(\frac{d^2 y(x)}{dx^2}\Bigg)  - \frac{dy(x)}{dx}\frac{d^3 y(x)}{ dx^3} = \frac{\frac{dy(x)}{dx}^2}{x^2}$$

*Let :*

$$\frac{dy(x)}{dx} = v(x)$$

*which yields :*

$$\frac{d^2 y(x)}{dx^2} = \frac{dv(x)}{dx}$$

$$\frac{d^3 y(x)}{ dx^3}= \frac{d^2 v(x)}{dx^2}$$

*You get :*

$$\Bigg( \frac{dv(x)}{dx}\Bigg)^2 -v(x)\frac{d^2 v(x)}{dx^2} = \frac{v(x)^2}{x^2}$$

$$\Rightarrow$$

$$\Bigg[-x^2 \Bigg( \frac{dv(x)}{dx}\Bigg)^2 + v(x)^2 + x^2\frac{d^2 v(x)}{dx^2}v(x)\Bigg]\frac{1}{x^2} = 0 $$

$$\Rightarrow$$

$$\frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{\frac{d^2 v(x)}{dx^2}}{v(x)} - \frac{\Bigg(\frac{dv(x)}{dx}\Bigg)^2}{v(x)^2} = 0 $$

$$\Rightarrow$$

$$\int \Bigg[\frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{\frac{d^2 v(x)}{dx^2}}{v(x)} - \frac{\Bigg(\frac{dv(x)}{dx}\Bigg)^2}{v(x)^2}\Bigg]dx = \int0dx$$

$$\Rightarrow$$

$$- \frac{1}{x} + \frac{\frac{dv(x)}{dx}}{v(x)} = c_1$$

$$\Rightarrow$$

$$\frac{dv(x)}{dx} = \frac{(c_1x+1)v(x)}{x}$$

$$\Rightarrow$$

$$\int \frac{dv(x)}{dx} dx = \int \frac{(c_1x+1)v(x)}{x} dx$$

$$\Rightarrow$$

$$\ln{v(x)} = \ln x + c_1x + c_2$$

$$\Rightarrow$$

$$v(x) =  e^{c_1x + c_2}x$$

$$\Rightarrow$$

$$v(x) = c_2 c_1^x x$$

*Substituting back for $\frac{dy(x)}{dx} = v(x)$, you get :*

$$\frac{dy(x)}{dx} = c_2 c_1^x x $$

$$\Rightarrow$$

$$y(x) =  \int c_2 c_1^x x dx = \frac{c_2 (\ln{(c_1)}x-1)c_1^x}{\ln^2c_1} + c_3 $$

Comment: You can also let $c_1:=e^{k_1}$ so that your solution looks better:
$$y(x) = \frac{c_2 (k_1 x-1)e^{k_1x}}{k_1^2} + c_3$$

Comment: @projectilemotion No need to change the final solution further, it's better to be in it's simplest form so readers don't get confused even for a spit second.